# This query wont return anything, i need advice on this

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

This is my code, it should send an email to a selected user.

If i attribute my own email as a string to $email it will send, but with this query it is not sending. $conncliente is my connection, and the $post is also working, but it's not getting my mail, no idea why...

```
mysql_select_db($database_conncliente, $conncliente);
    $codigo= mysql_insert_id();
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT 'mail' FROM 'usuarios' WHERE 'Uso_login' = '$usuario'", $conncliente);
    $email = mysql_fetch_assoc($pesquisa);
    $assunto = "Solicitação nº ".$codigo.".";
    $texto = "Sua solicitação nº ".$codigo.", com resumo \"".$_POST["resumo"]."\" foi aberta em ".$data."!";
    mail($email, $assunto, $texto);
```

Comment: Maybe you haven't setup a mail server properly?

Comment: try to print out $email and check what is comming? then you come to know what's the proble there

Comment: Andrew, as i said, if i write my mail to the variable it will work, the problem is the query wont return a mail to my variable;

Comment: if you are using mysql, you will have an issue with your single quotes around your `column`/`table` - `SELECT 'mail' FROM 'usuarios' WHERE 'Uso_login' = '$usuario'` should be `SELECT mail FROM usuarios WHERE Uso_login = '$usuario'` or `SELECT \`mail\` FROM \`usuarios\` WHERE \`Uso_login\` = '$usuario'`

Comment: Yeah  Sean i did it later, thanks anyway <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read mysql functions manual ant php.net. Also don't use mysql extension instead use PDO or mysqli.
There are numerous things that are wrong with this script. First of all this `$codigo= mysql_insert_id();` does nothing unless you have `INSERT` query before that. Also, main reason that this script doesn't work is incorrect usage of `mysql_fetch_assoc`, this function returns associative array so you have to address to the value by key to get it. Like this `$email=mysql_fetch_assoc($pesquisa)['mail']`.
Yet again I recommend you to use proper mysql extensions and to find proper guide on mysql in php.

Comment: i do have the insert thing before and unfortunately for this one system i need to use mysql, not msqli or pdo.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes than change email part to what I wrote and it should work

Comment: also i had to remove the '  ' from SELECT 'mail' FROM 'usuarios'

Comment: @PhiterFernandes yes, I thought it was `` sign

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = $result['mail'] ;
echo $result;
```

Create a variable which houses the information form the DB. Also i agree with the previous answer, try switching to PDO or MySQLi. From the release PHP 7 later this year mysql_query will be removed.

Comment: Can you add more description to your answer?